# Test if a value exist in a multidimensional array whether as a key or a value

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

Let's take this array as an example:

```
$arr = array(
    'foo' => 'foo',
    'bar' => array(
        'baz' => 'baz',
        'candy' => 'candy',
        'vegetable' => array(
            'carrot' => 'carrot',
        )
    ),
    'vegetable' => array(
        'carrot' => 'carrot2',
    ),
    'fruits' => 'fruits',
);
```

Now how to do a general search to check if a value exists whether as a key or a value in the array and his sub-arrays.

Comment: If you know foreach and you can write recursive functions you might be already on your way...

Comment: Thank you for these valuable advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we may use a double control

```
if(multi_array_key_exists($needle, $haystack)||deep_in_array($needle, $haystack))
{
    //Value exists
}
```

multi_array_key_exists function:

```
function multi_array_key_exists( $needle, $haystack ) { 

    foreach ( $haystack as $key => $value ) : 

        if ( $needle == $key ) 
            return true; 

        if ( is_array( $value ) ) : 
             if ( multi_array_key_exists( $needle, $value ) == true ) 
                return true; 
             else 
                 continue; 
        endif; 

    endforeach; 

    return false; 
}
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#92355

deep_in_array function:

```
function deep_in_array($needle, $haystack) {
    if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
        return true;
    }
    foreach($haystack as $element) {
        if(is_array($element) && deep_in_array($needle, $element))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Source: [php Checking if value exists in array of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435926/php-checking-if-value-exists-in-array-of-array/2435945#2435945)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#92355).

```
/** 
 * multi_array_key_exists function. 
 * 
 * @param mixed $needle The key you want to check for 
 * @param mixed $haystack The array you want to search 
 * @return bool 
 */ 
function multi_array_key_exists( $needle, $haystack ) { 

    foreach ( $haystack as $key => $value ) : 

        if ( $needle == $key ) 
            return true; 

        if ( is_array( $value ) ) : 
             if ( multi_array_key_exists( $needle, $value ) == true ) 
                return true; 
             else 
                 continue; 
        endif; 

    endforeach; 

    return false; 
}
```

Comment: you really don't like squiggly brackets, looks nicer, but could be confusing

Comment: @AmiroucheDouda: See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#97645 and: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#97465

Comment: I will do a double control, one for testing key exists and the other for testing the value exists..ok